# Force show keyboard on autofocus ios web browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios

There are lots of topics that address this issue, but all seem to be old and not relevant (ass further ios releases come out).

I have developed an applciation that is run via a web browser, be it safari or firefox (on an iPad). The webpage has an autofocus on an input, and I need to force the keyboard open.

I have tried without any success to do this with numerous jQuery hacks for focus, with timeouts etc etc. I have read that this might be possible with cordova, but before I re-develop the application is there anyway to do this with another JS libary thats easily "pluginable" to my existing html pages.

The closest I have come is this code, that when I press a button on the page, it then puts a focus on my form input and shows the keyboard:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      var button = document.querySelector('#button');
      var input = document.querySelector('#input');
      var focus = function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        var clone = input.cloneNode(true);
        var parent = input.parentElement;
        parent.appendChild(clone);
        parent.replaceChild(clone, input);
        input = clone;
        window.setTimeout(function() {
          input.value = input.value || "";
          input.focus();
        }, 0);
      }
      button.addEventListener('mousedown', focus);
      button.addEventListener('touchstart', focus);
    }, false);
  </script>
```

Is there any way I can simulate clicking the button, I have tried the following but this does not work on any browser, let alone IOS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#button").click();
});

</script>
```

So in short, can I simulate a click on this button? If I can get this working on my desktop, I will cross my fingers it then works on IOS.

Or if anyone else has any suggestions/ideas/hacks I would be extremely grateful.

Working example of my above code is taken from [here](http://4pcbr.com/topic/how_to_open_keyboard_on_ipad_with_js)

EDIT:

So I can force the button to be pressed after a time delay (with a MouseEvent), to simulate a real life touchdown event, but it only puts focus on the input box on ios, it does not bring up they keyboard prompt *sigh* (it does work on desktop browsers though), Looks like I will have to re-write in cordova.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        function focusinput(){
        var evt = new MouseEvent("touchstart", {
            view: window,
            bubbles: true,
            cancelable: true,
            clientX: 20,
            /* whatever properties you want to give it */
        }),
            ele = document.getElementById("button");
        ele.dispatchEvent(evt);
        } 


        function focusinputa(){
        var evt = new MouseEvent("mousedown", {
            view: window,
            bubbles: true,
            cancelable: true,
            clientX: 20,
            /* whatever properties you want to give it */
        }),
            ele = document.getElementById("button");
        ele.dispatchEvent(evt);
        }

        ;

        setTimeout(focusinput, 1000);
        setTimeout(focusinputa, 1500);


    });

</script>
```

EDIT2:

It seems there is no way at all to do this (as of writing this ios 9.1), inside a native html/js webpage, if anyone has any other solutions or ideas to test I would be happy to test them, but as for now I have had to resort to a a manual click of a button to focus the input and bring up the keyboard prompt.

Comment: You are not binding click event but `mousedown/touchstart`. So at least try `$("#button").mousedown();` or `$("#button").trigger('touchstart');`. But that's said, i'm really not sure it would work anyway.

Comment: Sadly this does not work, I should of added that I did try this.

Comment: Next step is trying to [dispatch event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/initMouseEvent), but again, i guess it wouldn't work

Comment: "This feature has been removed from the Web standards" Probably best not walk down this road..

Comment: Sorry, bad link, here it is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/MouseEvent but looks like Safari doesn't support it, what a surprise...

Comment: I can use mobile firefox so I will try this, fingers crossed.

Comment: Sadly it did not work, see edits in question.

Comment: I guess for some reason (security?), IOS doesn't want it. But instead of deploying a cordova app, cannot you just rethink your design and not autofocus by default the input? Or maybe you could force user in some way to click on a button, then use your previous snippet to set focus, open keyboard

Comment: I have had to do this for now, if anyone (future googlers included) finds a solution for this or a JS libary that will somehow trick users, i would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, and after a lot of tests i've got a simple solution, I hope it helps anyone ;)

First of all, Safari apparently make the focus, but do not open the keyboard. So I tried to change my **< button>** for a **< label>**. This worked for me.

```
<label for="search" id="mobile-search">Search</label>
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" value="">

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#mobile-search').on('click', function() {
    // do your stuff, in my case some class changes
  });  
</script>
```

Just be sure that you are not to using a **.preventDefault();** on the click event.